# Indian e-visa has duplicate surname

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, applications

I have been a granted an e-visa to Goa but, on the document, my surname is duplicated so that is looks like this: 'Neal Louise Neal' instead of just Neal Louise. Will this affect my entry at immigration or should I get another visa?

Comment: Giorgio, please remember that visa in case of a permission to enter a country is without a capital letter.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone reading an old thread it **IS** a risk that the airline will not let you on. My granted e-visa read "surname, first name, first name repeated". I left from the US to a connecting flight via Singapore Airlines. My middle name is not a repeat of my first name so Singapore Airlines did NOT allow me to board my flight to India on that detail alone.

It did not matter that the e-visa application required a scanned passport page and that government of India granted the visa that way. Singapore Airlines would not budge, said that India is "very strict" and told me to reapply for a new visa.

I called the e-visa 24/7 helpdesk and couldn't get through. After emailing the helpdesk they requested another copy of my passport page and later wrote that my original e-visa was **STILL** valid for entry into India and that my name on my granted e-visa could be read as "first name, first name, middle name, surname". **Still wrong**! I had missed the wedding I had planned to attend so I rebooked a flight back to the US and never made it to India.

This may be uncommon bad luck but I'll never fly Singapore Airlines again. From the airline's perspective, any probability greater than 0.0000% of being fined is grounds to deny you boarding.